# Running supreme commander forged alliance in dual monitor mode

Tags: linux, ubuntu, multiple-monitors, wine

I have ubuntu 14.04 64bit with wine 1.7 I installed FA via steam on wine and FAF as well.

both run decently although, FA does not detect my second monitor.

is this something wine is incapable of doing? What files would I have to edit to allow FA to detect both monitors and allow dual-monitor play?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did, run Supcom FA in windowed mode with a custom resolution set to fit your displays.  Also once game is loaded, use <kbd>Home</kbd> to split the screens.

On my Ubuntu 14.04 system, I have the following in a shell script for my dual 24" displays (1920x1200):

> wine explorer /desktop=0,3838x1146 "ForgedAlliance.exe"

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a single path to the exe since I run it through faf and since the executable arguments include countless random parameters including the names of the other players in the match.

I also don't have two same resolution screens so that solution doesn't work. Currently I just run it fullscreen but it's proving rather annoying to use wine : replay files can't run (I can only run the replays i find within the app, I can't use themes, and mumble won't install.)

i've  decided to abandon the wine route and go this route : https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=162768